# Estimating period and frequency of a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have ran a simulation and wish to estimate the dominate frequency and period of the time series generated using R. I have already used Fisher's K statistic to test whether the fluctuations are due to white noise and this indicted they are not. So the next thing I want to do is estimate the dominate period and frequency of these time series. (Each time series has 50000 time points).

The data has already been smoothed with a spline fit and I want to use the smoothed data for the estimation. The results don't have to be super accurate, at this point I just want a rough indication. As you can see from the picture there does appear to be regular fluctuations.

I know that in JMP it is very easy to do this, so I thought there might be a package in R that does a similar thing. I have been using the tseries package and wondering if this can be done using spectral analysis in tseries, but searching online I can't find exactly what I am looking for. Any help or direction (i.e. is there perhaps a better program to do this in that is more suited to time series analysis) would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Time series with 50000 time points, already smoothed. To me there appear to be quite regular fluctuations.]

Thanks!!

Comment: [Courtesy of Rob Hyndman](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/period-detection-of-a-generic-time-series)